# How to write unit test in OBJC, with different language and region, iOS 11?

Tags: ios, objective-c, swift, nsdateformatter

I am writing one unit test for date extension written in swift 4, unit test is still in OBJC(not converted to swift yet).

Basically, extension will generate POSIX string, if date string will be given in different language. 
e.g. If we are giving "२०१५-१०-०८T२२:४३:५३Z" string, extension will give us "2016-12-17T10:39:18+00:00" string which is posix string.

This scenario will be generated if, user's device lan. is different then English.

I don't want to pass hard coded string to my implemented function.

> What I want to write in my unit test is:-

- change application's lang. to arabic or so,
- generate this kind of string "२०१५-१०-०८T२२:४३:५३Z",
- pass this string to my magical function and it should return "2016-12-17T10:39:18+00:00" string.
- after test completes, change application lan. back to original.

> What I already tried is:-

```
[[NSUserDefaults standardUserDefaults] setObject:[NSArray arrayWithObjects:@"es", nil] forKey:@"AppleLanguages"];
[[NSUserDefaults standardUserDefaults] synchronize];
```

Do anybody have experience with this kind of use case, How to achieve this ?

Comment: You cannot dynamically change the device language at runtime.

Comment: @Kevin Ballard - Can I create string like this "२०१५-१०-०८T२२:४३:५३Z", by setting locale of dateformatter ? Just not hard-code, something which depends on user's language or region ..

Comment: Use `[NSLocale localeWithIdentifier:@"arabic_locale_or_something_here"]` with the date formatter

Comment: @Brandon - Thanks for your quick response. I tried, setting with NSLocale, not working... 

NSDateFormatter *mockFormatter = [[NSDateFormatter alloc] init];
mockFormatter.dateFormat = @"yyyy-MM-dd'T'HH:mm:ss.SSS'Z'";
mockFormatter.locale = [NSLocale localeWithLocaleIdentifier:@"ar-YE"];

Comment: @KevinBallard - thank for response.